# React native log spam

Tags: react-native

I was wondering if someone could help me out with an issue I recently started having. I recently updated React Native to 0.63.3 for one of my React Native projects and ever since then I've been getting massive amounts of console log spam that looks like this:

```
RCTView

Card@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:127934:36

CardContainer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:127610:22

RCTView
```

My initial thought was that it was coming from React Navigation onNavigationStateChange but disabling that doesn't seem to get rid of the log spam. Has anyone seen this before or know where it may be coming from?

Comment: have you figured this out?

Comment: I am also getting spammed. Did you solve this?